# What is the logical difference between PushButtonState.Default and PushButtonState.Normal?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I am using `ButtonRenderer.DrawButton` for a column with buttons with images in a DataGridView, and I am interested in when each `PushButtonState` value should be used.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.pushbuttonstate) is the official documentation. It says:

> - `Default` - The button has the default appearance.
> - `Disabled` - The button is disabled.
> - `Hot` - The button is hot.
> - `Normal` - The button has the normal appearance.
> - `Pressed` - The button is pressed.

The ones I do not understand well are `Default` and `Normal`. What is the difference between these two roles? In the screenshot below these 2 roles are combined with the `focused` `bool` parameter passed to the `ButtonRenderer.DrawButton` method.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The default Button is the one that raises the Click event when SpaceBar/Enter keys are pressed without explicit user selection (like in MessageBoxes, when a Button has a `DialogResult` value set). The normal one is a Button with standard rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About the default state**

According to user experience guidelines for Windows-based desktop applications for [button control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/ctrl-command-buttons):

> The default command button is invoked when users press the Enter key.
>   It is assigned by the developer, but any command button becomes the
>   default when users tab to it.

In windows forms, to set a button as the default button of a form, you can set it as `AcceptButton` of the form. For more information see [How to: Designate a Windows Forms Button as the Accept Button Using the Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/designate-a-wf-button-as-the-accept-button-using-the-designer)

**About other states**

If you take a look at [`ButtonStandardAdapter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonStandardAdapter.cs,c4630299fafb46d8) Which is responsible to draw a standard button, you will see:

```
private PushButtonState DetermineState(bool up) {
    PushButtonState state = PushButtonState.Normal;

    if (!up) {
        state = PushButtonState.Pressed;
    }
    else if (Control.MouseIsOver) {
        state = PushButtonState.Hot;
    }
    else if (!Control.Enabled) {
        state = PushButtonState.Disabled;
    }
    else if (Control.Focused || Control.IsDefault) {
        state = PushButtonState.Default;
    }

    return state;
}
```

And `IsDefault` returns `true` for a button which is set a `AcceptButton` of a `Form`.